# Pandas DataFrame: How to calculate the rolling mean of both grouped and shifted data in version >0.19

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the followig `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'x2': [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
                   })

> df
  name  x1  x2
0    a   1   4
1    a   2   3
2    a   3   2
3    a   4   1
4    b   1   4
5    b   2   3
6    b   3   2
7    b   4   1
```

I would like to calculate a rolling mean of `x1` and `x2` with`window`-size of 2 and `min_periods` of 1. The mean should be grouped by the `name` and the input to the `mean`-function should be shifted by one row, that is, the resulting row with index 2, should be calculated from rows (0,1). So for `x1` the rolling mean in row 2 should be (1+2)/2 = 1.5.

**In Pandas version <= 0.18** I would do this:

```
> df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x.shift(1), window=2, min_periods=1))
    x1   x2
0  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  4.0
2  1.5  3.5
3  2.5  2.5
4  NaN  NaN
5  1.0  4.0
6  1.5  3.5
7  2.5  2.5
```

Which is perfect, since row 0 and row 4 do not a any data, within each name group, of length 1, and the result should be `np.nan`.

In Pandas 0.19 and later the `rolling_mean`-function and functions alike, are throwing:

```
FutureWarning: pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for DataFrame and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
DataFrame.rolling(min_periods=1,center=False,window=2).mean()
```

**So in Pandas version >= 0.19** this is the best approach I could come up with:

```
df_shifted = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
> df_shifted.groupby('name').rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
       name   x1   x2
name                 
a    1    a  1.0  4.0
     2    a  1.5  3.5
     3    a  2.5  2.5
b    5    b  1.0  4.0
     6    b  1.5  3.5
     7    b  2.5  2.5
```

But this removes the `nan`-rows which I would like to keep for array-dimension reasons and returns a DataFrame with `MultiIndex`.

Is there a nice one-line-kind-of-way of solving this while keeping the `nan`-rows and returning a DataFrame with a flat index?

**EDIT**
The method should handle nan's like the 0.18-method. So if `x1 = [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]` the rolling mean at index 1 should return `np.nan`, but the rolling mean at index 2 should return `2.0`, since `(np.nan + 2)/1 -> 2.0` that is number of non-nan's is less or equal to `min_periods`.

Comment: Did you mean `df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean())`?

Comment: I should have specified this in the question, but I would like the rolling mean to handle `nan`'s the same way as the 0.18-method. So counting the `nan`'s according to `min_periods` and retuning the mean if there are fewer nan's then `min_periods`. But haven't tried your suggestion :-)

Comment: @NickilMaveli: Your method is actually doing the right thing regrding nan's... sorry didn't notice right away. Thanks! If you put it in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to correct or comment on the above, but there's a mistake in the above. Therefore I'm adding this as a separate answer. There is an omitted closing parenthesis for the `apply` in the above. It should read: df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()) This is the correct way to calculate a rolling mean of both grouped and shifted data in Pandas > 0.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the Deprecation warnings, starting with version `0.19.1`, you can rewrite the syntax as shown:

1. shift the `DF` by 1 level
2. compute rolling mean

---

```
df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
#                                  DataFrame.rolling(*args, **kwargs).mean()
```

[image]